# React Native : How to get the list of apps installed in mobile phone in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Is there a way to get the list of all apps installed in the device with its detail in react native.

I had tried this npm package but it does not work at all.

https://github.com/progaymanalaiwah/react-native-android-installed-apps

Comment: You can use the package -  react-native-android-installed-apps

Comment: @Hemant It does not work

Comment: @AshadNasim Did you achieve it?

Comment: @GokulKrishna no, I was not able to find that. and then I moved to some other projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a list of all installed apps on a mobile phone using React Native, you can use the react-native-launcher-kit bundle. This bundle provides a simple API to access various features related to app launchers on Android devices, including the ability to get a list of all installed apps.

To get started, install the react-native-launcher-kit package by running the following command in your project directory:

```
npm install react-native-launcher-kit
```

Once you have installed the package, you can use the getApps() method to get a list of all installed apps on the device. The method returns an array of objects, where each object represents an installed app and contains information such as the app name, icon, and package ID.

Here is an example of how to use the getApps() method:

```
import { InstalledApps } from 'react-native-launcher-kit';

const apps = InstalledApps.getApps();
console.log(apps);
```

In addition to getting a list of installed apps, the react-native-launcher-kit bundle provides other features related to app launchers, such as checking the current default launcher, monitoring battery percentage and charging status, checking if a package (bundle ID) is installed, and opening system settings. You can also open an app using its bundle ID, directly access the "Set as default launcher" screen, and open the alarm app directly.

The react-native-launcher-kit bundle is an efficient solution for developers who want to create Android launchers using React Native. With its seamless user experience and simplified development process, this bundle is an essential tool for anyone working on mobile app development.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've recently published an npm module for this specific purpose.

The package name is react-native-android-installed-apps-unblocking. It is multi-threaded, which does not block the UI while loading the apps.

For more details check out my GitHub [repo](https://github.com/HydromanAG/react-native-android-installed-apps-unblocking).

Comment: This is not working for me. 
npm installed and used the code snippet as in repo.
All I'm getting is this:
Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-android-installed-apps-unblocking`
 However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything that works for both Android and iOS at the same time. My suggestion is to have a look at this libraries and to create your own version that can handle both:

**Android**: https://github.com/redpandatronicsuk/react-native-check-app-install

**iOS**: https://github.com/dimapaloskin/react-native-installed-apps