# React Native: How to find the packages installed in Android Emulator using Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli

I am looking how to find if an application is installed in Android/IOS, I found `react-native-shared-group-preferences` is offering this feature. However, I am finding that regardless the value in packageName, the execution always goes to the catch block:

```
const IsInstalled = async () => {
  const packageName = 'com.google.android.youtube';
  try {
      const isAppInstalled = await SharedGroupPreferences.isAppInstalledAndroid(
        packageName,
      );
      // IF IS INSTALL
      console.log(`isAppInstalled: ${isAppInstalled}`);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      // IF IS NOT INSTALL
      console.log(`error: ${e}`);
    }
};
```

I have tried several packages with no success. In Android Studio I see Youtube app:
[image]

I am expecting to print the value returned by `isAppInstalledAndroid` function, but instead this is going to the catch. When attempting to print the error, then I get undefined.

The following are the dependencies in package.json:

```
dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-shared-group-preferences": "^1.1.23",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
```

Thanks a lot for your insights on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native : How to get the list of apps installed in mobile phone in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491851/react-native-how-to-get-the-list-of-apps-installed-in-mobile-phone-in-react-na)

Comment: Thanks @ThanhalPA, yes I am looking for getting the list of apps installed. The function is returning an array of all installed apps in the following way:  [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. Do you know how could I print properly in console.log?

Comment: I am printing like this:
const result = InstalledApps.getApps();
result.map(appObj => console.log(JSON.stringify(appObj)));

Comment: Dont use JSON.stringify here. just log the appObj and see what all props are there. then use the props you need